# Revoking Bearer Token and Refresh Token - ServiceStack

Tags: servicestack

I want to enforce a single user session feature for my Angular app because my customers share a single account with their coworkers.

The issue currently, with my implementation. is revoking a valid token stored a client's local storage, particularly a valid Refresh token.

The scenario is:

1. User 1 logs in with valid username and password, the bearer token will expire in an hour, the refresh token will expire in two weeks
2. User 2, uses the same username and password two hours later. User 2 is prompted that they are logged in on another device and asked the question of they would like to expire that session and start a new session.
3. User 2 says yes and the now User 1's session in invalid.

The problem is that User 1 still has a valid Refresh token.

I have no way revoke this refresh token. My Auth API will accept is valid and I will not know whether it is User 1 or User 2's refresh token.

Do I need to start storing refresh token values in my database to resolve this issue? I also thought I could use a different JwtAuthKeyBase64 for User1 and User2, as a way to invalidate User1's token but this doesn't seem like a good way to be using the ServiceStack JwtAuthProvider.

Answer (score 0):

The [JWT RefreshToken](http://docs.servicestack.net/jwt-authprovider#refresh-tokens) is used to contact the Auth Server to fetch a new JWT Bearer Token. It will only return a BearerToken if the User still has Access so you can lock the User Account by populating `UserAuth.LockedDate` which will prevent the user from retrieving a new JWT Bearer Token.

If you want more custom validation you can [implement IUserSessionSource](http://docs.servicestack.net/jwt-authprovider#requires-user-auth-repository-or-iusersessionsource) and throw an Exception in `GetUserSession()` to return an Error Response instead of the JWT Bearer Token.

Comment: This makes sense, the only issue is that User1 and User2 will have the same UserId, so I will not know which RefreshToken to revoke, unless I stored the current RefreshToken in the database correct?

Comment: @BrianOgden Neither option gives you access to the RefreshToken. User 1 and User 2 should not be using the same Username/Password unless they're the same User. The only real option is to add a Global Request Filter checking for `GetAccessToken` Request DTO and short-circuit the Request when you want to deny that RefreshToken from getting access.