# Persisting RefreshToken OnAuthenticated - ServiceStack

Tags: servicestack

This question is related to this question here: "[Revoking Bearer Token and Refresh Token - ServiceStack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50690152/revoking-bearer-token-and-refresh-token-servicestack)"

When a user has successful logged in with their username and password I would like to stored the user's RefreshToken in the database. My thinking is that I can use the RefreshToken as a unique identifier of the user's session and if the user has had their tokens revoked and can short circuit the GetAccessToken request based on the RefreshToken passed in the GetAccessToken request and check against the RefreshToken I have persisted.

I would like to persist the RefreshToken in my auth API in the my overrided OnAuthenticated implementation:

```
 IHttpResult OnAuthenticated(IServiceBase authService,
            IAuthSession session, IAuthTokens tokens,
            Dictionary<string, string> authInfo)
```

This seems like the appropriate place. On the initial credentials auth request, `IAuthTokens tokens` is null,  authService.Request.GetBearerToken returns null.

Is there any what to access the RefreshToken the client will receive and persist it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Session Cookies](http://docs.servicestack.net/sessions) are the Unique Identifier for the Session and is the [key used to save the session against](http://docs.servicestack.net/sessions#formatting-of-keys-used-in-cache-providers).

But the point of JWT's is that there is **no server session state** since it's encapsulated in the JWT Bearer Token. So I don't understand this approach of maintain server state, invalidating the primary benefits of using JWT's.

The Server can access the returned RefreshToken by registering a [Global Response Filter](http://docs.servicestack.net/request-and-response-filters#global-response-filters) and checking for the `AuthenticateResponse` DTO or registering a [Typed Response Filter](http://docs.servicestack.net/request-and-response-filters#typed-request-filters) which invokes a Typed filter for the Registered DTO, e.g:

```
public override void Configure(Container container)
{
    RegisterTypedResponseFilter<AuthenticateResponse>((req, res, dto) =>
    {
        var jwt = dto.BearerToken;
        var refreshToken = dto.RefreshToken;
    });
}
```

Comment: Yes I didn't have strong understanding of the ServiceStack Session, no need to use the RefreshToken, just use the Session cookies, thanks @mythz